# Pattern to use to handle a event with awaitable method in c#

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous

Like the subject of this post, anybody can suggest me the best way to handle an event fired with an async method in c#?

Example

```
// Before:
MyPosClass.EventBluetoothCommunicationCompleted+= (sender, ErrorCode) =>
            {
                // implementation on event fired
            };

// After:
var result = await MyPosClass.WaitBluetoothCommunicationCompleted();
```

I noticed this answer
[Await async with event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252696/await-async-with-event-handler)
Can it be a solution?

Thank you!
Lewix

Comment: The answer to this is in the body of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12865848/14357) question. Use a `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Can you please better/clearly state your problem and what exactly you want to solve?

Comment: I have implemented an interface to comunicate via bluetooth from app to mobile pos. Now i'm working to implement a class and i would like it exposed simply methods that wait until comunication is performed and completed. Solution of @spender works! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution of @spender seems the cleanest and it works!
[General purpose FromEvent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865848/general-purpose-fromevent-method)

Now my awaitable method
with this improvement [TaskCompletionSource throws "An attempt was made to transition a task to a final state when it had already completed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787840/taskcompletionsource-throws-an-attempt-was-made-to-transition-a-task-to-a-final)
becomes:

```
public Task<TransactionData> PerformTransactionAwait()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TransactionData>();

    EventHandler<TransactionInfo> callback = null;
    callback = (sender, TransactionDataResult) =>
    {
        MyInterface.TransactionPerformed -= callback;
        tcs.SetResult(TransactionDataResult);
    };

    MyInterface.TransactionPerformed += callback;
    MyInterface.PerformTransactionAsync();

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Thank you! Lewix

Comment: Improvements to avoid memory leaks and let to call the method more thank once here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787840/taskcompletionsource-throws-an-attempt-was-made-to-transition-a-task-to-a-final

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.